# How to delete an element inside a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got multidimensional array.

From each subarray, I would like to remove / unset values with price more than 1500.

Array

```
$item = array(
    'phone' => array(
        array(
            'Item' => 'S5',
            'info' => array(
                array('seller' => 'John', 'price' => 1800),
                array('seller' => 'Mason','price' => 1200),
                array('seller' => 'Alex','price' => 1500),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'Item' => 'iPhone 5',
            'info' => array(
                array('seller' => 'Depay', 'price' => 1900),
                array('seller' => 'David', 'price' => 1450),
                array('seller' => 'Daemon', 'price' => 1600),
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

my code:

```
foreach($item['phone'] as $key =>$price)
{
    foreach($price['info'] as $info => $price2 )
    {
        if ($info['price'] >= 1500)
        {
            unset($item[$key][$info ]);

        }
    }
}
```

Why this code does not work? Can this be done? and if yes... How???

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You referring to the wrong element level:

```
foreach($item['phone'] as $key =>$price)
{
    foreach($price['info'] as $info => $price2 ) // $price2
    {
        if ($info['price'] >= 1500) // should be $price2
        {
            unset($item[$key][$info ]);

        }
    }
}
```

You should point into `$price2` in your condition:

```
if ($price2['price'] >= 1500) {
```

Then, on unsetting, you'll need to point/walk into indices

```
// write the complete address of this element you want to unset
unset($item['phone'][$key]['info'][$info]); 
//             ^              ^   don't forget this since they are part of the structure
```

So all in all:

```
foreach($item['phone'] as $key =>$price)
{
    foreach($price['info'] as $info => $price2 )
    {
        if ($price2['price'] >= 1500) {
            unset($item['phone'][$key]['info'][$info]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RmSZwF)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like

```
foreach($item['phone'] as $key => $price) {

    foreach($price['info'] as $info => $price2 ) {

        if ($price2['price'] >= 1500) {

            unset($item['phone'][$key]['info'][$info]); 

        }
    }
}
```

In if condition you are using key $info, it should be $price2.

Here is the running code https://ideone.com/Mk7VfU

Comment: Agreed `$info` should be `$price2` however this still doesn't unset items with prices equal or above 1500